# Angular UI $modal component transition

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I am using the $modal component from Angular UI (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).
Whenever the modal opens it sort of scrolls down from the top. 
I simply want it to open instead of the fancy roll-from-top effect that it has right now

Plnkr: 
     http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: Your plunker does not have a modal example.

Answer (score 12):

Changing the option `windowClass` to `"modal fade in"` removes the animated slide.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      windowClass: "modal fade in"
 });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XAAdnUnA5dikT00jZYIM?p=preview)

In addition to that removing the fade class will believe it or not remove the fade effect.

Comment: Tried it and it does work. Makes the modal load much snappier.

Comment: This stops the slide-in animation for modal open, but closing the modal still has the slides-out animation. Also, removing `fade` appears to make no difference - [see updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K3eLx1h00Tk7F6UQrvkm?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to use css to disable the animations. I've achieved it adding:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
     transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

To the stylesheet. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/43oCGtDb3CaP9bwgW5gm?p=preview

Comment: if I want to just change the fade speed, what would I do?